# Designing constructors around type erasure in Java

Tags: java, conventions, type-erasure

Yesterday, I was designing a Java class which I wanted to be initalized with Lists of various generic types:

```
TheClass(List<String> list) {
   ...
}

TheClass(List<OtherType> list) {
   ...
}
```

This will not compile, as the constructors have the same erasure.

I just went with factory methods differentiated by their names instead:

```
public static TheClass createWithStrings(List<String> list)
public static TheClass createWithOtherTypes(List<OtherType> list)
```

This is less than optimal, as there isn't a single obvious location where all the different options for creating instances are available.

I tried to search for better design ideas, but found surprisingly few results. What other patterns exist for designing around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I would love to know a neat fix for this issue.

I encounter the same problem often, and I usually fix it by just introducing a dummy parameter (such as `Void`) to the constructor, which is of course not the most elegant fix, but the best one I know of so far.

Comment: This is not the worst solution. I use it sometimes. I just add a dummy parameter of type `Void`. Scala uses the same trick, but the dummy parameter is implicit, so on the call side two methods call look the same.

Answer (score 1):

Note, it would be possible to add method overloading on generic arguments with erasure, although wildcards would make it more difficult.

I would suggest using creation method with a name based on the interpretation of the types. `String` by itself doesn't have much meaning. `createWithThingNames`, or something.

Some statically-typed languages do not have method overload at all (deliberately).

Comment: Good point on the method names. 'String' is superfluous, as it's already in the method signature.

Comment: @Internet Friend: "`Strign`" lacks as much meaning in the parameter type as it does in the method name.

Answer (score 0):

Differents solutions :

1) with tabs

```
class TheClass
{
 TheClass(String[] strings)   {}
 TheClass(Object[] others) {}
}
```

2) with generics

```
class TheClass<P>
{
 TheClass(P generic) {}
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean "1) with arrays", but let's not go back there. Generics wouldn't work if the behaviour was different based on element type, which it probable is (and therefore there should probably be some sort of name-based identification).